# Help in evaluating $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1000^x}{x^x} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I suspect that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1000^x}{x^x} = 0.$$
However, I do not know how to prove that this is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: write  ${1000^x\over x^x}= ( {1000\over x})^x$. Note that $0<{1000\over x} $ and that eventually, ${1000\over x}<{1\over 2}$. Then compare (use the squeeze theorem) with ${1\over 2^x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$\frac{1000^x}{x^x} = \exp(x (\ln 1000 - \ln x))$$
What can you say about $\ln 1000 - \ln x$, and then about $x (\ln 1000 - \ln x)$, as $x \to +\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

If $x > 2000$ then $\frac{1000^x}{x^x} < \frac{1}{2^x}$.

This echoes an answer I gave recently to another problem. Not sure what that means.